# I can not put value of the servlet in the JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to validate the login and password of the user, in that if not enter the login fields and password will appear a message in the screen "Please fill in the fields of login or password" or if the user type the wrong username or password will appear an "Incorrect Login or Password" screen message but it does not show the messages.

Why does not it show the message on the jsp page?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

  String vazio="Por favor preencha os campos de login ou senha"; 
   String incorretos="Login ou senha incorretos"; 

   String login = request.getParameter("login");
  String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

    Cliente cli= new Cliente();
       LoginDAO login2= new  LoginDAO();


    Cliente login_validacao=login2.validacaoLogin(login,senha);


   if(login_validacao.getLogin()==null && login_validacao.getSenha()==null){
   request.setAttribute("vazio", vazio); 

   }
   else if(login_validacao.getLogin().equals(request.getParameter("login")) 
  & login_validacao.getSenha().equals((request.getParameter("senha")))){

 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
 }
  else{
  request.setAttribute("incorreto", incorretos); 
  }

  }

  <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-
 awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="login-form">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
 <h2 id="AcesseConta"><span>Acesse sua Conta</span></h2>
 <label for="vazio_resposta">${vazio}</label>
  <label for="validacao">${incorreto}</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>   
     <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
 Login:<input type="text" id="login" name="login" ><br/><br/>
 Senha:<input type="text" id="senha" name="senha" ><br/>
 <a href="">Não é cadastrado?Cadastre-se</a><br/><br/>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>   
     <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
          <div id="teste"></div>  
   <button type="button" onclick="login()" >Entrar</button>  <button 
  type="button" onclick="" >Esqueceu a Senha?</button> 
 </div>

</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question (:-))

Comment: I asked now, brother.

Comment: I think maybe the expression `${incorreto.incorretos}` inside your `<label>` element should be just `${incorreto}`.

Comment: I changed it and just put $ {incorreto} but still did not show the message on the page

Comment: It should be `${incorreto}`, with no space between the `$` and the `{`...

Comment: I changed and I put without space but did not show a message

Comment: because in my login validation it returns the data correctly from the query made in which I get the login password and compares if the retrieved value of the query that step to the getLogin object and getSenha is null, 
If you are null, I'll pass the message that this null to page jsp

Comment: but I do not know why it's not showing the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of validating HTML Form Using Controller/Servlet You Can use 'REQUIRED' tag in html as follow.

```
Login:<input type="text" id="login" name="login" Required><br/><br/>
 Senha:<input type="text" id="senha" name="senha" Required><br/>
```

And Displaying message on JSP from servlet use below code

for Servlet

```
        if(login_validacao.getLogin()==null && login_validacao.getSenha()==null)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?vazio=" + URLEncoder.encode(vazio, "UTF-8"));

    }
       else if(login_validacao.getLogin().equals(request.getParameter("login")) 
      & login_validacao.getSenha().equals((request.getParameter("senha"))))
   {

     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
     rd.forward(request, response);
   }
      else
   {
      response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?incorretos=" + URLEncoder.encode(incorretos, "UTF-8"));
    }
```

FOR JSP

```
<c:if test="${!empty vazio}">
    <p  style="color:red;" align="center">${param.vazio}</p>
</c:if>
```